# Deported from US for working illegally but actually I was not working?

Tags: visas

We are planning to move to Canada and Australia as I was deported from US for charges that I was working illegally when I don't have right to work.

I am scared to apply for Canada or Australia PR as I think there are chances of rejection.

Please help me in solving this confusion.

Thanks 
Swara

Comment: Who are "we"? Where are you now? Do you have any proof of the claim in the title (and why is it only there) that you were not actually working? What do yo expect us to do?

Comment: If you want any useful help, you need to tell us your nationality, your location now and your long term expectations. But if you really want to move and stay in a country for a long time the question does not belong here, maybe it does belong on the expats site, the people there also needs those details.